# fill textbox on second combobox selection changed in cascading combobox in windows form using c#

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have 2 cascading combo-box in windows form application. I have textbox for price and unit. when I select first combobox, second combobox gets populated. I want textbox for price and unit to be filled only on second combobox selection.
My problem is when the form is loaded both textboxes are filled with values from table and not on combobox selection changed.

my code is:

```
private void Purchase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'supplierDataSet.Supplier' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.supplierTableAdapter.Fill(this.supplierDataSet.Supplier);
        fillName();

        comboBoxName.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }



   private void fillName()
   {
       string str = "Select distinct Item_Name from Item";
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ashish-pc\;Initial Catalog=HMS;Integrated Security=True"))
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))
           {
               using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
               {
                   DataTable dtItem = new DataTable();
                   adp.Fill(dtItem);

                    comboBoxName.DataSource = dtItem;
                   comboBoxName.DisplayMember = "Item_Name";
                   comboBoxName.ValueMember = "Item_Name";

               }
           }
       }
   }
   private void fillMake()
   {
       string str = "Select Item_Make from Item Where Item_Name=@Item_Name";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ashish-pc\;Initial Catalog=HMS;Integrated Security=True"))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Name", comboBoxName.Text);
                using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dtItem = new DataTable();
                    adp.Fill(dtItem);
                    comboBoxMake.DataSource = dtItem;
                    comboBoxMake.ValueMember = "Item_Make";
                    comboBoxMake.DisplayMember = "Item_Make";


                }
            }
        }

   }

  private void comboBoxName_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBoxName.Text))
      {
          comboBoxMake.Enabled = true;
          fillMake();
          comboBoxMake.SelectedIndex = -1;
      }
  }

  private void comboBoxMake_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBoxMake.Text))
      {
          textBoxPrice.Enabled = true;
          textBoxUoM.Enabled = true;

      }

      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ashish-pc\;Initial Catalog=HMS;Integrated Security=True");
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Item Where Item_Make='" + comboBoxMake.Text + "' AND Item_Name='" + comboBoxName.Text + "'", con);
      SqlDataReader reader;
      try
      {
          if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
          {
              con.Open();
          }
          reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          while (reader.Read())
          {
              textBoxPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Price"]);
              textBoxUoM.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Unit"]);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
      finally
      {
          if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
          {
              con.Close();
          }
      }
  }
```

I am stuck here. please help.

Comment: What is the SelectedValue of the ComboBoxes when you load the form? Is it empty(as it should be because of SelectedItem = -1) or is it the first item from the DataTables?

Comment: I just noticed that you don't have SelectedItem = -1 but SelectedIndex = -1. Try changing it to SelectedItem. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing SelectedIndex = -1 to SelectedItem = -1 in Purchase_Load and ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Phoenix, I tried changing selectedIndex to selectedItem. But it does not show selected value empty and my problem is that when the form loads both combobox are filled and respective textboxes are also filled. please help

Comment: Hmm... that's weird. Try setting Text to String.Empty. Maybe that will work since it is what you are using to check if there is a selected item.